# Significant reputation difference among meta and main sites

Tags: bug, reputation, per-site-meta

I just noticed the significant reputation difference in site switcher popup for main and meta sites:

> [image]

According to reputation graph on stackexchange.com current meta reputation level I had two months ago on November 2018:

> [image]

On the meta site itself on the top bar the reputation is correct.